# In 1.7.2 exploration disconnects all clients

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm playing on a SMP server which is quite old. There are many chunks from many different versions of minecraft. Most were generated with a bukkit modded server jar, but with only dynmap installed - so no significant changes (any?) to vanilla map-gen mechanics except as released from Mojang.

Now, whenever exploring new areas (new biomes anyone?) every few seconds everyone experiences a timeout error and must re-connect. The server didn't go down, evidenced by all mobs and entities being identical to before disconnect.

The question is: is the server simply under-powered for new chunk generation and we are all disconnecting because the server isn't sending keep-alives often enough? Is anyone else experiencing the problem? And, finally, is dumping more memory enough, or do I need a new mobo/processor?

Comment: what does the server output say?

Comment: Please tell me what the server says about this bug. But judging on your error you might just be exceeding the RAM limit your server can handle. Increasing this isn't hard just [CLICK THIS](http://www.wikihow.com/Increase-Java-Memory-in-Windows-7). If that doesn't help tell me what error the server gives you. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the disconnect error you're getting is

```
Internal Exception: io.netty.handler.timeout.ReadTimeoutException
```

then this is [a known bug in 1.7.2](https://mojang.atlassian.net/browse/MC-34947) that seems to be triggered in a variety of situations. (The 1.7 update brought entirely new networking code, and this is one of the downsides of brand-new code.)

On our server we've also been encountering this issue while out exploring new chunks. It has been frustrating not to be able to explore freely without disconnecting and affecting everyone else on the server. This error happens even if you are the only person online. Faster connections and allocating more RAM to the server doesn't fix a thing. It doesn't mean your sever is underpowered.

Here is [the current open bug report for this issue](https://mojang.atlassian.net/browse/MC-34947). Keep an eye on that, and hopefully it will be solved for the next update.

Comment: @BillyMailman I really have to squint and pretend I'm reading this for the first time to see what you mean, but yeah, I see what you mean. It reads *really strongly* like a "me too" though. That could/should be fixed by editing.

Comment: @BillyMailman There, that sounds more like answering the question with personal experience rather than just sharing a me-too. Explaining the content of the link first makes a big difference.